# "I [had] visited them two months ago"

Tags: tenses, past-tense

> A. I had visited them two months ago.
>   B. I visited them two months ago.

Which one is correct?

Comment: (A) is only grammatical if a nearby sentence (or another clause in the same sentence) references a time between two months ago and now: *"I had visited them two months ago, when they seemed perfectly happy, so I was quite surprised to hear they filed for divorce last month."* The past perfect is allowable here because *"had visited"* comes before *"was surprised to hear"*.

Comment: @PeterShor Din't quite get you . Please frame a sentence for what you are stating .

Comment: A. is pluperfect. B. is perfect. So, A. is further back in time than some other event.

Comment: As an aside, no whitespace goes *before* a period in English. (Or in any other language, for that matter.)

Comment: Also, I think I must say (although I've given an answer) that this question should really be in the http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PeterShor I can only guess the point of the exercise is to teach the OP not to use *ago* with Past Perfect, but to use *before that* instead. Whether or not that's a useful exercise, is of course a separate question.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Helpful comments

Comment: Both versions are fine. It depends on context as to which one might be preferred by the writer or speaker.

Answer (score 1):

"Which one is correct" cannot be answered without further context. However this information can help you decide for yourself.

A. is [pluperfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect#English). B. is [present perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect#English). So, A. is further back in time than some other event.

And in general:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)#English

Comment: Wow ! a wiki post .Could have explained in one line instead. Still doesn't helps me.

Comment: @user63166 The 2nd paragraph explains clearly enough. Maybe you need to go to ell.stackexchange.com if you don't understand.